What is the name of the movie about childrens dream watchers?
I'm looking for a movie that is in English. I saw it a couple years ago. It was on YouTube Movies but isn't there anymore.
The movie had a neighborhood with what seemed like a dark ghostly figure in the foreground. The opening panned a regular looking neighborhood with 5 or 6 people walking down the street. They jumped on the houses and went into different children's rooms. At first you're not sure whats going on because the scenes change. You think they are scaring the children but at the end you find out they are dream chasers keeping nightmares away from the children.
I don't recall any of the actors but they were all looked like they were in their early to mid 20's.

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

You're describing one of the first scenes of Ink from 2009.

As the light fades and the city goes to sleep, two forces emerge. They are invisible except for the power they exert over us in our sleep, battling for our souls through dreams. One force delivers hope and strength through good dreams; the other infuses the subconscious with desperation through nightmares. John and Emma, Father and Daughter are wrenched into this fantastical dream world battle, forced to fight for John's soul and to save Emma from an eternal nightmare. Separate in their journey, they encounter unusual characters that exist only in their subconscious. Or do they? 

The scene unfolds exactly as you've described. You can see a part of it here, and here's the trailer:




@KDees No problem, but if this is the correct answer, please don't forget to approve it (by clicking on the check mark next to it).
